# Bad request error 400 when submitting a form

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am getting Error Response 400 when submitting the form. I have a form which was working fine before i added a drop down list which displays gender to the user from DB. The Drop down is displaying the data correctly but when i am submitting the form i am getting an error. This only happened when i added the drop down list.

**RegistrationController.java :-**

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationController.class);
    private StaffService staffService;

    @Autowired
    private GenderDao genderDao;

    @Autowired
    public RegistrationController(StaffService staffService) {
        this.staffService = staffService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/register")
    public String registerStaffPage(Model model) {
        List<Gender> genders = genderDao.findAll();
        Iterator<Gender> genderIterators = genders.iterator();
        Map<Gender, String> genderMap = new LinkedHashMap<Gender, String>();
        while (genderIterators.hasNext()) {
            Gender gender = genderIterators.next();
            genderMap.put(gender, gender.getGender());
        }
        model.addAttribute("gendersMap",genderMap);
        model.addAttribute("staffRegistrationBean", new StaffRegistrationBean());
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/registerStaff")
    public String registerStaff(@ModelAttribute("staffRegistrationBean") StaffRegistrationBean staffRegistrationBean,
            @Valid StaffRegistrationBean staffRegistrationBeans, Errors errors, Model model) {
        // if (errors.hasErrors())
        // return "register";
        staffService.createStaff(staffRegistrationBean);
        return "RegistrationDone";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.debug("RegistrationController Bean has been Initialized.");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        logger.debug("RegistrationController Bean has been Destroyed.");
    }
}
```

**StaffRegistrationBean.java**

```
public class StaffRegistrationBean {
private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String Organization;
    private String phoneNo;
    private Gender gender;
    // getter and setter follows
}
```

**regsiter.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Registration Form</h1>
    <form:form id="regForm" modelAttribute="staffRegistrationBean"
        action="registerStaff" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="userName" cssErrorClass="error">
                        <spring:message code="userName" /> : 
                    </form:label> <form:input path="userName" name="username" id="username"
                        cssErrorClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gender: <form:select path="gender">
                        <form:options items="${gendersMap}" />
                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="organization" cssErrorClass="error">
                        <spring:message code="organizationName" /> : 
                    </form:label> <form:input path="organization" name="username" id="organization"
                        cssErrorClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="password" cssErrorClass="error">
                        <spring:message code="password" /> : 
                    </form:label> <form:input path="password" name="password" id="password"
                        cssErrorClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="firstName" cssErrorClass="error">
                        <spring:message code="firstName" /> : 
                    </form:label> <form:input path="firstName" name="firstname" id="firstname"
                        cssErrorClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="lastName" cssErrorClass="error">
                        <spring:message code="lastName" /> : 
                    </form:label> <form:input path="lastName" name="lastname" id="lastname"
                        cssErrorClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <%-- <tr>
                <td><form:label path="gender">
                        <spring:message code="gender" /> : </form:label>
                <td><form:select path="${gender}">
                        <form:options items="${genderList}" id="id" itemValue="gender">
                        </form:options>
                    </form:select></td>
            </tr> --%>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="email" cssErrorClass="error">
                        <spring:message code="email" /> : 
                    </form:label> <form:input path="email" name="email" id="email"
                        cssErrorClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="phoneNo" cssErrorClass="error">
                        <spring:message code="phoneNo" /> : 
                    </form:label> <form:input path="phoneNo" name="phoneNo" id="phoneNo"
                        cssErrorClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="register"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**

- Error :-

**

HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

Type Status Report

Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

GenderMap is a map that has the model to display on the screen. The key is Gender class and value is the gender description. The user will select a gender which will be referring to an id in the gender table.

The Entire code is available at - https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/ExpenseCalculator_Nex_Gen/tree/DevBranch

Go to the URL - localhost:8080/ExpenseCalculator/register

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think action="registerStaff" not pointing to method

Comment: @Ali.Mojtehedy Nope. Wrong URL returns 404, but OP got 400.

Comment: A Http 400 May occur due to a wrong request payload object. In your case the Staffregistrationbean. In this class you define a variable gender of Type Gender, but i guess in your jsp you just submit a String?

Answer (score 2):

As Razmin said, spring is trying to populate your ModelAttribute (which is of type StaffRegistrationBean) from the body of the POST request (automatically filled by the HTML form).

---

If you look at the POST request body you will see something like ***gender: 1***. **Spring cannot map this Integer to a Gender (even if this Integer simply refers to the id of your Gender..)**.
You will have to retrieve manually the Gender from your DB, and set it to your Model.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when spring can't populate the ModelAttribute from HTML form.

staffRegistrationBean ModelAttribute can't convert Html's Gender attribute to your Gender object

Answer (score 0):

It worked when enabled "Host" headers in postman